# numpy and Wolfram Alpha give different eigenvectors

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, wolfram-mathematica, linear-algebra, wolframalpha

For the following matrix, I tried to get eigen values and eigenvectors from Numpy and Wolfram Alpha, respectively. The eigen values are the same, but the eigenvectors are different.

Results from Numpy:

```
In [36]: aa
Out[36]: 
array([[10, 14],
       [14, 20]])

In [37]: eigvals, eigvectors = np.linalg.eig(aa)

In [38]: eigvals
Out[38]: array([ 0.13393125, 29.86606875])

In [39]: eigvectors
Out[39]: 
array([[-0.81741556, -0.57604844],
       [ 0.57604844, -0.81741556]])
```

Results from Wlfram Alpha (prompt: `((10, 14), (14, 20)), solve the eigenvalues and eigenvectors`):
[image]

As you can see, the eigenvalues are the same from two software, but the eigenvectors are different. Aren't the eigenvectors supposed to the same, too? Could someone clarify? Thank you!

Comment: The eigenvectors are the same except for a normalization constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eigenvectors can be scaled up or down as their magnitude does not matter.

The preferred way to show eigenvectors is as unit vectors which is what **numpy** produces. The reason it is preferred is that it makes diagonalizing the source matrix easier if the matrix of eigenvectors as columns is orthonormal.

```
X = | -√(1/2 + 5√221/442)  -√(1/2 - 5√221/442) | = | -0.8174   -0.5760 |
    |  √(1/2 - 5√221/442)  -√(1/2 + 5√221/442) |   |  0.5760   -0.8174 |
```

The results from **wolfram** have chosen a different scaling for each eigenvector with the last element being **1**.

```
X = | √221/14 - 5/14    -√221/14 - 5/14 | = | 0.7047   -1.4190 |
    |       1                  1        |   | 1.0000    1.0000 |
```

Both results are correct because both can diagonalize the original matrix. You can check this with

```
D = inv(X) * | 10 14 | * X = | 15 - √221      0      | = |0.1339   0.0000 |
             | 14 20 |       |    0        15 + √221 |   |0.0000  29.8660 |
```

which is a diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues in the diagonal elements.

---

It seems **wolfram** does a symbolic manipulation, which for the 2×2 matrix

```
A = | A11  A12 |
    | A21  A22 |
```

produces the eigenvectors symbolically by solving a system of equations and setting the last coordinate equals one.

```
X = | (D+A11+2*A12-A22)/(D-A11+2*A21+A22) (D-A11-2*A12+A22)/(D+A11-2*A21-A22) |
    |                                   1                                   1 |
```

with `D = √(4*A12*A21 + (A11-A22)^2) > 0`